# How build array("key":value) in js with loop json ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I’m trying to modify a vector map with values obtained by AJAX and JSON.

Map function perfect with this array key value:

```
var visitorsData = {
    "tac": 564, 
    "moq": 400, 
    "lim": 1000, 
    "apu": 800, 
    "caj": 760, 
    "ama": 300, 
    "lib": 700, 
    "lam": 600,
};
```

And the function that takes this values is this:

```
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
  map: 'peru',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  regionStyle: {
    initial: {
      fill: "#c6c6c6",
      stroke: "#204d6f",
      "stroke-width": 1,
      "stroke-opacity": 1
    },
    hover: {
      fill: "#ed0000",
      "fill-opacity": "1"
    }
  },
  series: {
    regions: [{
      values: visitorsData,
      scale: ["#3c8dbc", "#2D79A6"], //['#3E5E6B', '#A6BAC2'],
      normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
    }]
  },
  onRegionLabelShow: function(e, el, code) {
    if (typeof visitorsData[code] != "undefined")
      el.html(el.html() + ': ' + visitorsData[code] + ' new visitors');
  }
})
```

Now I want to take values taken from a JSON and with this build a new `visitorsData` but no function. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: globalMapUrl, //obtain json
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    var visitorsData = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var item = data[i];
      visitorsData[item.nombre] = item.numeroDeAnuncios;
    }
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert("Ajax failed to fetch data")
  })
```

Comment: whats inside data can you provide a sample of the data that is coming from ajax

Comment: So right now in your ajax call you are adding more items to the map, but you are wanting to create new map instead so the old data is cleared?

Answer (score 0):

Your `visitorsData` looks like a json object not a vector array
Create a new JSONObject instead of an Array and you should be good

instead of,

```
var visitorsData = new Array();
```

try

```
var visitorData = {};
```